# Mapbox GL NavigationControl Events

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have an instance of a Mapbox GL map, after load of my data source I am calling `fitBounds()` to change the map's center and zoom to fit my data set. I've also attached a number of event listeners to this map because I want to know when the user manually changed the map's zoom or position.

Mapbox also triggers 'movestart' and 'zoomstart' on `fitBounds()`, though I'm getting around that problem by checking for the presence of the `originalEvent` property in the event callback.

The problem is, I also have a `NavigationControl` added to the map, and user interactions triggered through its zoom or rotate buttons fire my map events without the `originalEvent` property. I cannot find any way in the Mapbox documentation to listen attach event listeners to the `NavigationControl`, nor a way to differentiate between a zoom / pan initiated by a fitBounds call vs. a user interaction through that component.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to attach mouse / touch event listeners to the `NavigationControl` component? Or perhaps is there some property within the event objects that will tell me the source of the event?

Simplified code sample -

```
this._userMoved = false;
this._map = new mapboxgl.Map(options);

// listen for user actions that update the map display
['movestart', 'zoomstart', 'boxzoomstart', 'rotatestart', 'pitchstart'].forEach((action) => {
  this._map.on(action, (e) => {
    if (e.originalEvent) {
      // if this property is set, the event in question was triggered by an actual user ineraction.
      // EXCEPT when the user interaction came from the NavigationControl, hence the problem
      this._userMoved = true;
    }
  });
});
this._map.on('load', () => {
  // add the control after map load
  this._map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(),'top-left');
  this._setMapData(); // adds my data source to the map
  this._setMapView(); // calls this._map.fitBounds() using my data source
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your need is specifically to handle a specific event (fitbounds) that is being called once, then you can do this:

```
this._map.once('moveend', e => {
   // do whatever you do after the fitbounds event.
   this._map.on(['movestart', 'zoomstart', 'boxzoomstart', 'rotatestart', 'pitchstart'], userMovementHandler)
});
```

***EDIT***

I just looked more closely at the documentation and there is indeed an `eventData` parameter to `fitBounds` which is intended to solve exactly this problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RldmFnZSIsImEiOiJGcW03aExzIn0.QUkUmTGIO3gGt83HiRIjQw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
}).on('moveend', e => { 
    if (e.source === 'fitBounds') {
        console.log('Caused by fitBounds');
    } else {
        console.log('Caused by user');
    }
})
map.fitBounds([140,-42, 150,-37], {}, {source: 'fitBounds'})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a great idea; however (and I didn't mention this in the original post) my map data will continue to change over time, and as those changes come in, I'll be re-fitting the map to bounds until the user makes their first interaction.

Comment: Excellent find! Not sure how I missed this in the docs.

There is one other issue where map.resize() triggers a `moveend` event and it is not possible to pass `eventData` within that call, but that should be taken up with Mapbox and I've found a workaround. Thanks!